# Scan of barcode probleme using Xamarin on UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, barcode

I'm using a Zebra DS3678 Scanner to scan barcode in my application.
My barcode is supposed to return `E2126287`

So I create a command which is triggered when the scan is finished :

```
_myEntry.Behaviors.Add(
                    new Prism.Behaviors.EventToCommandBehavior()
                    {
                        EventName = "Completed",
                        Command = SearchEntryCompletedCommand
                    }
                );
```

And the execution :

```
private async Task ExecuteSearchEntryCompletedCommand()
        {

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TxtNumColis))
            {
                if (SearchSODCommand.CanExecute())
                    SearchSODCommand.Execute();
            }

        }
```

The text property of my entry is bind on `TxtNumColis`

The problem is, in my `ExecuteSearchEntryCompletedCommand`, the most of time, the TxtNumColis is empty.

Sometimes, its `E212` instead of the full barcode.
The scanner had no settings except for language and add a carriage return at the end of the data.

It happens only on UWP.
I already search some issues about that ou some parameters on the scanner but nothing works.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: the scanner just inserts the text into the `_myEntry` field?  You can see the value in the Entry, but the bound string does not contain the data?

Comment: That's it. The command is like the completed event of the entry. And it is triggered in the beginning of the data and not at the end

Comment: that sounds like a config or driver problem if it is sending a CR before the data is input

Comment: No driver seems necessary but i'll try to install one. For the config, I tried to find something but nothing sounds good